# JSP - Retrieving row name from query

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to retrieve the row name from query to compare it with a java string. Is there anyway to do it?

```
    <sql:query var="result" dataSource="jdbc/affablebean">
                SELECT * FROM parking
    </sql:query>
    <table border="1">
        <!-- column headers -->
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${result.columnNames}">
                <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
        <!-- column data -->
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                    <%
                    String check = (String)session.getAttribute("id");
                    **String check2 = ??????** //want ${row}
                    out.print(check+"<br>");
                    out.print(check2);
                        if(check == check2){
                    %>
                    <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
                    <%
                                   }
                    %>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

So far, I am able to get the if statement to work. The only problem is I have no idea how to retrieve  check2 to compare it with check1

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the code obtaining ResultSetMetaData is missed.

Please add:

ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = result.getMetaData();